# What are the proper file formats for Freezy graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am using Tensorflow and Inception v3 CNN. 
I want to save the trained network using the [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)

What I have done till now is saving the model in input_graph.pb during training, by using tf.write_graph, and my thoughts are that this should be the “input graph” in the FLAGS.

1. When it comes to the remaining fields, such as input saver, output nodes and initializer nodes, I`m not sure how to create the proper file formats?
2. Another question is how to use the created .meta file from the training?

I would really appreciate if you could take some time to help me.